# tokens not matching (PHP)

Tags: php, sql

I saw that this question has been asked a few times before but I still can't figure it out.
I'm still new to php but I have an idea of what's going on.

here's the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Pro-tip. if you are inserting data into all the columns in your table, you do not need to specify the column names in the query. Makes your code neater and readable

Comment: The number of tokens appear to match, check for typos.

Comment: what if statement? and how did you generate the token

Comment: @flosculus will do, thanks

Comment: @akintunde was referring to the 'if ($_POST)' part. I didn't write this code. Just trying to help fix it (asking SO because i'm stuck)

Comment: Side note: whatever you think you need `strip_tags()` for is probably the result of a misconception.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for the tip but it wasn't me

Comment: Change the order of `':image'=>$image,
                ':slug'=>slug($name),` to `':slug'=>slug($name), ':image'=>$image,`

Comment: what does the function `slug()` do?

Comment: @sam Are you sure the error is here? are there any other queries in your script?

Comment: @flosculus  Okay so in this CMS, there is an 'awards' field per product where you can add the awards it has won. The awards field would not save so I had a look at the code and found that 'awards' is nowhere to be seen in the code above. I decided to try and add :awards to the code above (in the same way all the others are done) but it didn't work. I deleted everything I tried and now the error is showing. there is 'updateProduct' and 'saveProduct' and I added :awards to both. I will add 'updateProduct' above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:wine_of_origin` is missing from your second query bound parameters.

Comment: Man, Thank you so much. You have really helped me! It's working :)